# Class doesn't get added on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I add a classname with Jquery, and it works, but only starts working AFTER my first click.
The code only addes the 'class' attribute the first time, but without the value.
Can anyone see what I do wrong?
(the class just add's a top margin in CSS)

```
(function(){
    $(document).ready(Setup)

    function Setup(){
        $("#navBarBehandeling").on('click',CheckDropDown);
    }
    $("#navBarBehandeling").on('click',CheckDropDown);
    function CheckDropDown(){
        var t = $(this);
        if(t.attr('aria-expanded')=='false'){
           $('main').addClass("mt-9");

        }
        else{
            $('main').removeClass("mt-9");
        }

    }
}()
```

And here's my css:

```
.mt-9{
    margin-top: 9rem;
}
```

and here's my html:

```
<head>
   CDN's for Jquery and bootstrap
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="navBarBehandeling"> navbar with dropdown here></div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <p> blablabla </p>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html, specifically how you define the `main` element.

Comment: Please clarify: question title *"class doesn't get added"*, question text:  "*code adds only the first time*"  - also what's "without the value"?   I'm also wondering how you expect `t.attr('aria-expanded')` to change so that it does something different on 2nd click.

Comment: In the body i have the elements: header, main, aside and footer, and I want to move the whole main-part away from the header. So main is just a standard html-tag (like 'div').
Area-expanded  returns the bool true or false, (automatticaly set by bootstrap) and that's how I determine if my expandable navBar is open or closed.
But I tested those values and they work correct, its only the setting of the class

Answer (score 0):

You can just do **!t.attr('aria-expanded')** to make it work

```js
$("#navBarBehandeling").on('click',CheckDropDown);
function CheckDropDown() {
    var t = $(this);

    if (!t.attr('aria-expanded')) {
       console.log('addClass');
       $('main').addClass("mt-9");
    } else{
      console.log('removeClass');
      $('main').removeClass("mt-9");
    }
}
```

```css
.mt-9{
    margin-top: 9rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
          <div id="navBarBehandeling"> navbar with dropdown here></div>
      </header>
      <main>
          <p> blablabla </p>
      </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work. it's actually the same, but a shorter way of writing it...

Comment: Your code dont work at all... This one works

Comment: that's the point, mine works perfectly, only the first click he does not add the class

Comment: This work from the first click

Comment: I wonder if the problem could be that I use bootstrap CSS, maybe it overwrites something on the first click. (bootstrap link is not in my snippet)

Answer (score 0):

Use document ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#navBarBehandeling").on("click", CheckDropDown);
      function CheckDropDown() {
        var t = $(this);
        if (t.attr("aria-expanded") == "false") {
          $("main").addClass("mt-9");
        } else {
          $("main").removeClass("mt-9");
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I did use document.ready in an IIFE function, i just didnt add all the code to my snippet because it does not have anything to do with the problem